# how i can to make the count to get the amount of something

Tags: sql

I have this attributes in my table(Invoices):
CustomerID, InvoiceID

Now i'm try to show the amount of Invoices of every CustomerID, i'm using GROUP BY and count but it's doesn't work.

```
select customerID ,count(invoiceID) as amountOfinvoices
FROM Invoices
group by customerID,invoiceID
```

Comment: `group by customerID` only.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  SQL Server and MySQL are 2 completely different products.  Which one are you using?

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't help us help you.  Doesn't work how?  Error out?  No result? Wrong result?  If it error out, where's the error?

Answer (score 1):

```
select customerID ,count(invoiceID) as amountOfinvoices
FROM Invoices
group by customerID;
```